# AWS Amplify migrate GraphQLTransformer to V2

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I recently added the @index annotation to my GraphQL schema in my Amplify backend and am now getting the following error:

`SchemaValidationError: Your GraphQL Schema is using "@index" directive from the newer version of the GraphQL Transformer`

I've followed the migration guide referenced in the error: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/migration/transformer-migration/ but it doesn't actually indicate how to perform the migration itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GraphQL Transformer version is managed in `amplify/cli.json`

You simply need to edit the file and set the following two properties:

```
  "features": {
    "graphqltransformer": {
      ...
      "useexperimentalpipelinedtransformer": true,
      "transformerversion": 2,
      ...
    },
```

From there you can do an `amplify push` or a `amplify codegen models` and assuming all changes referenced in the guide (https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/migration/transformer-migration/) have been catered for all will work.